# count total paired members of the tree by sqlquery

Tags: sql-server

I am having a table tbltestingtree representing the tree structure, Member_Id is the id of the member, Parent_Id represent the Parentid of that member , Lefts and Rights tells us that the member is attached to the left or right of the Parent.
**My problem is that i have to make a sqlquery that counts the total number of pared members for any particular parent ,**

Ex-  currently member with id 1 has 3 pairs with id 2,3 and 4
 currently member with id 2 has 1 pair with id  4

```
  Member_Id     Parent_Id      Lefts         Rights
     1               Null       Null          Null  
     2                1          1            Null
     3                1         Null           1
     4                2          1            Null
     5                2         Null           1
     6                3          1            Null
     7                3         Null           1
     8                4          1            Null
     9                4         Null           1
```

image of tree is here:
http://imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&l=img4/4605/65ai.jpg

Comment: Actually i know only simple insert, update ,delete queries, but i don't know how to approach in sub queries and how could i solve this problem

Comment: You actually want to find the number of children for each node, correct?

Comment: No, Childrens are different thing, I want to find out the Paired childrens i.e those children which have their left and right nodes filled

Comment: Ok, it's clearer now.

Comment: According to your example, 1 has pairs with 2 and 3, and 2 has pairs with 4 and 5, but you are saying differently in your question. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTestingTree](
            [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [ParentId] [int] NULL,
            [IsLeft] [bit] NULL,
            [IsRight] [bit] NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_tblTestingTree] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [Id] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
        GO
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblTestingTree] ON
        INSERT [dbo].[tblTestingTree] ([Id], [ParentId], [IsLeft], [IsRight]) VALUES (1, NULL, NULL, NULL)
        INSERT [dbo].[tblTestingTree] ([Id], [ParentId], [IsLeft], [IsRight]) VALUES (2, 1, 1, NULL)
        INSERT [dbo].[tblTestingTree] ([Id], [ParentId], [IsLeft], [IsRight]) VALUES (3, 1, NULL, 1)
        INSERT [dbo].[tblTestingTree] ([Id], [ParentId], [IsLeft], [IsRight]) VALUES (4, 2, 1, NULL)
        INSERT [dbo].[tblTestingTree] ([Id], [ParentId], [IsLeft], [IsRight]) VALUES (5, 2, NULL, 1)
        INSERT [dbo].[tblTestingTree] ([Id], [ParentId], [IsLeft], [IsRight]) VALUES (6, 3, 1, NULL)
        INSERT [dbo].[tblTestingTree] ([Id], [ParentId], [IsLeft], [IsRight]) VALUES (7, 3, NULL, 1)
        INSERT [dbo].[tblTestingTree] ([Id], [ParentId], [IsLeft], [IsRight]) VALUES (8, 4, 1, NULL)
        INSERT [dbo].[tblTestingTree] ([Id], [ParentId], [IsLeft], [IsRight]) VALUES (9, 4, NULL, 1)
        INSERT [dbo].[tblTestingTree] ([Id], [ParentId], [IsLeft], [IsRight]) VALUES (10, 5, 1, NULL)
        SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblTestingTree] OFF

declare @ParentId as int
set @ParentId=2 

;with Child as
(
    select id,ParentId from tblTestingTree where id=@ParentId
    union all
    Select tblTestingTree.Id,tblTestingTree.parentId from tblTestingTree 
    inner join Child 
    on tblTestingTree.ParentId=Child.Id
)
select count(*) from (select c.ParentId from Child c where c.ParentId!=@ParentId
group by c.ParentId
having COUNT(c.ParentId)>1)a
```

Comment: after some work i am improving my query. Now my query don't use any temprory table

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query you're looking for:

```
WITH children AS (
  SELECT Parent_Id, COUNT(Parent_Id) AS NR_CHILDREN
  FROM TREE
  GROUP BY Parent_Id
  HAVING COUNT(Parent_Id) >= 2
  )
SELECT T.Parent_Id AS 'PARENT', T.Member_Id AS 'CHILDREN'
FROM TREE T JOIN
  CHILDREN C ON T.Member_Id = C.Parent_Id
WHERE ISNULL(T.Parent_Id, 0) <> 0
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2971e/14) with the code.

Comment: Thanks , For Your time sir,But I am Not Looking for this result, Parent with id 1 has 3 childrens which have their left and right node filled and those 3 childrens have id's 2,3 and 4 respectively. I hope now you got my question

Comment: Then, that is something different. I have updated my answer so it will display nodes 2,3 and 4 as children of node 1. You did not state in your question that this is possible. I assumed that your tree is binary.

Comment: @Ashu Also, with 3 children at the top node, you cannot have 3 Paired elements for Node 1 (this would mean that there are a `MINIMUM` of 10 nodes = NODE 1 + NODE 2 + NODE 3 + NODE 4 + 2 children for each of node 2,3 and 4 which is 6. 1 + 3children +  6 grandchildren = 10). Either there is MORE data, more nodes connected to nodes 2,3,4 than you have posted in your question, or .. something else is missing.

Comment: sir, If we talk about memberid 1 then its paired children will be 2,3,4 so the answer will be counting them that is 3, but if i talk about memberid 2 then its paired children will be member with id 4 because it is the only child of member 2 which is paired so its answer will be 1, i want such type of query

Comment: Can any one please help

Comment: @Ashu I upvoted your question so maybe someone else will manage to 'help' you.